# unable to display expo push token on apk

Tags: react-native, expo

I am using react native expo bare workflow

When I open the app on expo client I am able to see the device token on screen but when I convert it to apk
by using
**expo build:android**
It doesn't show token.

This is my code.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import * as Notifications from "expo-notifications";
import * as Permissions from "expo-permissions";
import { TextInput } from "react-native";

export default function App() {
    const [token, setToken] = useState("");
    const [value, onChangeText] = React.useState("Useless Placeholder");

    useEffect(() => {
        getPushNotificationPermissions();
    });

    getPushNotificationPermissions = async () => {
        const { status: existingStatus } = await Permissions.getAsync(
            Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS,
        );
        let finalStatus = existingStatus;

        // only ask if permissions have not already been determined, because
        // iOS won't necessarily prompt the user a second time.
        if (existingStatus !== "granted") {
            // Android remote notification permissions are granted during the app
            // install, so this will only ask on iOS
            const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
            finalStatus = status;
        }

        // Stop here if the user did not grant permissions
        if (finalStatus !== "granted") {
            return;
        }
        console.log(finalStatus);

        // Get the token that uniquely identifies this device
        console.log(
            "Notification Token: ",
            (await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync()).data,
        );

        setToken((await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync()).data);
    };

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>{token}</Text>
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
    },
});
```

And also i don't get a push notification on apk but it works on expo client.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using bare workflow, You should pass your `experienceId` in an object to `getExpoPushTokenAsync`, the value of your `experienceId` is `@your-username/your-project-slug`